# Ruby passing hash to class variable

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm not understanding how to pass a hash to a class then access it from a class method. When the hash is displayed it is nil. If I try to iterate through it using .each I get a 'nil:nilClass' error. What am I missing here?

Is this not possible or am I approaching it wrong?

```
#bin file
@my_hash = YAML.load_file(@filename)
@tester = TestClass.new(@my_hash)
@tester.show

#lib file
class TestClass
 attr_accessor :my_hash

 def initialize(my_hash={})
   @my_hash
 end

 def show
   puts @my_hash.inspect
 end
end
```

Comment: Where is the class method? You seem to only have instance methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to assign the instance variable in the initializer.

```
def initialize(my_hash={})
  @my_hash = my_hash
end
```

You wrote

```
def initialize(my_hash={})
  @my_hash
end
```

In your code, the value of `@my_hash` is set to `nil`. In fact, your code is equivalent to

```
def initialize(my_hash={})
  @my_hash = nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `initialize` method, you aren't actually assigning `my_hash` to the instance variable. Try this:

```
def initialize(my_hash={})
  @my_hash = my_hash
end
```